# Why is the specific warning violation from gcc not shown with -std=c11/c99 on this code?

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

If I compile this program

```
main() {}
```

with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic smallest_program.c
```

gcc says:

```
    smallest_program.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
 main() { }
 ^
smallest_program.c: In function ‘main’:
smallest_program.c:2:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 main() { }
```

If I add C11 or C99 as the standard:

```
 gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic smallest_program.c
```

the warning is:

```
smallest_program.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
 main() { }
```

I appears that <strike>C11</strike> C99 has added an implicit return statement in main if you omit it. But why does the warning for the missing return type no long contain the specific warning that was violated: **[-Wreturn-type]** ?

This is from *gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2*

Comment: I think C11 will consider that the return is void by default so it will not asked for a return statement but it will still warn you that the main return should be an int

Comment: The option you probably want is -pedantic, not -Wpedantic (pedantic is not an error class AFAIK)

Comment: @trentcl `-pedantic` [is a synonym for](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno-fatal-errors-288) `-Wpedantic`

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard no, `main` returns `int` in C11

Comment: @Scooter it seems you're asking about a particular feature (or lack of it) of gcc , rather than a question about C? Maybe file a bug report.

Comment: @Oktalist Thanks, it seems this is a relatively recent addition as it was not in [gcc 4.7.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) but I shall be better informed hereafter.

Answer (score 3):

Because the implicit `int` rule has been dropped, so it is not a question of what warning flags are on but under C11 this *must* give a diagnostic, with or without warning options. And as a consequence, you can't silence that diagnostic.

Comment: It does the same thing under -std=c99 so maybe dropped in C99? I don't understand though -  if a return type must be there - then shouldn't it be an error, not a warning?

Comment: @Scooter, yes probably already dropped in C99, I don't remember exactly. For the warning, no the C standard only imposes that a "diagnostic" is issued in case of an error. Whether or not compilation continues and for which cases is left to the compiler implementation. Just treat all warnings as errors :)

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the difference in the warning message about the implicit `int` return, implicit `int` is not allowed in C11 (IIRC, since C99), so the warning will always appear, regardless of what warnings/errors you enable (it is "`enabled by default`".) In other words, you don't have to be asked to be warned, because the implementation has to give you a diagnostic.

Concerning the control reaching the end of a non-void function, C has has an implicit `return 0;` in the `main` function since C99. That is why compiling in C11 mode does not produce a warning.

Comment: That wasn't my question. I am asking why the [-Wreturn-type]  is not shown in the warning when you add -std=c11

Comment: @Scooter So why are you going on about the implicit return statement? Maybe clarify your question?

Comment: He is talking about the missing flag in warning.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have missed void at the start of main - that will default to an int - as it also assumes an int as an passed in parameter as there's no void there too.

I would suggest you try the following for main ...

```
int main( void )
{
     return( 0 );
}
```

I am old, maybe things have changed.   :-)